# Best data structure to hold SQLAlchemy engines

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

Considering having N users and M databases, where some users may share the same database, i.e. N >= M.

Now I would like to hold the SQL Alchemy engine instances for the M lazy connection pools of the databases. I would like to use a dict where the keys are the users id and the values are the engine, so that I can easily access the query engine of each user.
The problem is that I would like also to create the instance only if it's the first time, otherwise using an already created instances, and also to save the "connection string" infos of each database.

Should I exploit two data structures, or use a complex one to design this? I know it's a simple question but I would like to get the experience of someone who has already designed this.

```
users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
connection_strings = ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str3", "str1"]
```

Comment: "*M databases*" - how such a database is represented in your case, as a conn string? Post a sample

Comment: I am thinking about it so here the question. In order to create the engine SQL Alchemy needs an URL instance as connection_string, so I either have the URLs already or dicts with the needed fields to build the URLs

Comment: suppose the URL/connection_string is correct. In my case, it is

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd employ [Custom Vertical Partitioning](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/persistence_techniques.html#custom-vertical-partitioning).
Assuming that you already have `{<user_id>:<conn_string>, ...}` mapping, say **`user_db_map`**. 
From it we need to collect the unique connection strings (or `sqlalchemy.engine.URL` objects) to create a unique set of engines. It's OK to do that on `URL` instances, since they are immutable objects, thus can be hashable.

```
# engines for unique db source urls
url_engines_map = {url: create_engine(url) for url in set(user_db_map.values())}
```

Then, we link each user to the respective pre-established engine:

```
user_engines_map = {user: url_engines_map[url] for user, url in user_db_map.items()}
```

To promote a multiple-engine Session declare a custom `Session` type to override [`Session.get_bind()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get_bind) method:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker


class RoutingSession(Session):
    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
        if isinstance(mapper, User):  # your User model/table 
            return user_engines_map[mapper.id]
        elif isinstance(mapper, str):  # user id
            return user_engines_map[mapper]
        else:
            raise UnboundExecutionError()

Session = sessionmaker(class_=RoutingSession)
```

---

Adjust the above strategy to your actual inputs and conditions.